# Azure App Service Multi Instance: Do I need to change my web app code

Tags: azure

I just discovered that azure app services can scale both up and out. For out this means creating multiple instances. So my question is do I need to change my asp.net web app to support this? For example if a user asks to run an async report that runs in background and then comes back later to download the report will it just work? What about security. If a user has authenticated, gotten a cookie, and then leaves the app alone for a while and then continues will it work? Is there any documentation to help.

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't support, you can always switch on server affinity. This ensures the request will route back to the same server. However this is **not recommended** you want any server to respond, rather the same one they started with.

You don't need to change your code, it will just work and its Azure is smart enough to route traffic to the servers for you, so your question about async, yes that will 100% work.

If you use store information in the cookie, it should work without server affinity, but if you use session, then you most likely will need to turn it on (depending on where session is stored - inproc, sql). Here is an article about server affinity https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/

Hope that helps